# The Archimedean property of the real-number system: completeness axiom

Tags: calculus

If $\ x$ is an arbitrary real number, prove that there is exactly one integer $n$ which satisfies the inequalities $n\leq x < n + 1$.

Comment: It is obvious to see this, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Step 1: prove there is no integer $m$ such that $n<m<m+1$.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @vadim123, I think you meant $n<m<n+1$.

Comment: Wow! You're right. Very good answers there. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $x>0$, the general case then follows easily.

Existence: By the Archimedean property, the set $\{k \in \mathbb{N}: k>x \}$ is non-empty, and hence contains a least element, call it $n$. Since $n-1<n$, it follows that $n-1\le x$.

Uniqueness: Use that, if $a<b$ are integers, then $b-a<1 \iff a=b$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I developed your ideas and made the demonstration step-by-step.
I'm self-studying for the first time Calculus (Apostol), and LA (Axler), in order to prepare for a Real Analysis course. That's why such a basic question.

Comment: Hey!
The set you described with a least element, has an infimum. It follows from the uniqueness of infS that n must be unique. Right?

Comment: The ser has a least element, which in particular is the infimum of the set, which is unique. However it is not immediate from this uniqueness that the integer with the  you want is also unique.